# Sympy can not solve an Integral

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

I tried to solve the integral ∫sqrt(cot(x))dx but sympy didn't evaluate it.

```
x = smp.symbols('x', real= True)
I = smp.Integral(smp.sqrt(smp.cot(x)),x)
I.evalf()`
```

or

```
smp.integrate(smp.sqrt(smp.cot(x)))
```

both just output:∫sqrt(cot(x))dx

I tried using .doit() or .evalf() but i didn't work either

Comment: You can use `evalf` only with definite integrals e.g. `Integral(sqrt(cot(x)), (x, 0.5, 1)).evalf()`